How to import ts files into worker threads in Nodejs
I have a js (detect_nudity.js) like this:
import {parentPort, workerData} from "worker_threads";
import Util from "../../../Common/Server/Util.ts";

const nude = `/abc/nude.jpg`;
const notNude = `/abc/not_nude.png`;
const notNudeResultPromise = Util.isImageNude(notNude);
const nudeResultPromise = Util.isImageNude(nude);
parentPort.postMessage({nude: await nudeResultPromise, notNude: await notNudeResultPromise});

When I try to use this script in a worker thread, I get this error:
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for \abc\Common\Server\Util.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:45) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

Is there a "correct" way to import ts files to be used in a worker thread?
